# How to add a temporary .docx file to a zip archive in django

Tags: python, django, zip, python-docx

here is my code for downloading a zip file, containing a .docx file,

```
def reportsdlserien(request):
    selected_sem = request.POST.get("semester","SS 2016")

    docx_title="Report_in_%s.docx" % selected_sem.replace(' ','_')

    document = Document()
    f = io.BytesIO()

    zip_title="Archive_in_%s.zip" % selected_sem.replace(' ','_')
    zip_arch = ZipFile( f, 'a' )

    document.add_heading("Report in "+selected_sem, 0)
    document.add_paragraph(date.today().strftime('%d %B %Y'))

    document.save(docx_title)
    zip_arch.write(docx_title)
    zip_arch.close()
    response = HttpResponse(
        f.getvalue(),
        content_type='application/zip'
    )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + zip_title
    return response
```

the only problem is, it also creates the .docx file, which i dont need. I wanted to use BytesIO for a docx file too, but i cant add it to the archive, the command `zip_arch.write(BytesIOdocxfile)` doesn't work. Is there another command to do this? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`writestr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) function to add some bytes to the archive:

```
data = StringIO()
document.save(data)  # Or however the library requires you to do this.
zip_arch.writestr(docx_title, bytes(data.getvalue()))
```

I've only done this with StringIO, but I don't see why BytesIO would't work just as well.

Comment: yeah, that worked, i was using os.remove() before, but that seemed so ugly. Thanks a lot!